# Spectral Decomposition of a symmetric matrix times a diagonal matrix

Tags: covariance-matrix, matrix-decomposition, matrix-inverse

I would like to find the inverse of the sum of a Kronecker product and a diagonal matrix. I found this [answered here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140316/how-to-calculate-the-inverse-of-sum-of-a-kronecker-product-and-a-diagonal-matrix), but I don't see how the last step is valid.

> > Because of the fact that $C$ is diagonal, the spectral decomposition of $D^{−1}C$ itself is easy to obtain from that of $D^{−1}$.

It says that if we know the spectral decomposition of a symmetric matrix $D^{-1}$, we can easily find the same for $D^{−1}C$, where $C$ is diagonal. Can someone explain how to do this?

Since $D^{−1}C$ is not symmetric and not guaranteed to be orthogonally diagonalizable anymore, I don't quite see how this solution would work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $D^{-1}$ is symmetric, and $C$ is diagonal, then you're right that their product is not necessarily symmetric, and as a result, any spectral decomposition will not be "easy to obtain."

For example, say 
$$
D^{-1} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1\\
1 & 3
\end{array}\right]
$$
and $C = \text{diag}(2,3)$. Then 
$$
D^{-1}C = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
4 & 3\\
2 & 9
\end{array}\right]
\neq
(D^{-1}C)'.
$$

Comment: Thank you. But since this has the form $UDV'$ instead of $UDU'$, how would I simplify the next step? ie, $(I + UDU')^{-1} = U(I + D) ^{-1}U'$, does a similar simplification exist for **$(I + UDV')^{-1}$** ?